# Android Studio, cannot resolve symbol method

Tags: java, android

I've been following this guide on Google Developers and have stumbled into some errors. 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Here is the code I'm having problems with:

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

    if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                mIsResolving = true;
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e("", "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                mIsResolving = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
            // error dialog.
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
        }
    } else {
        // Show the signed-out UI
        showSignedOutUI();
    }
}
```

and the errors:

Error:(133, 17) error: cannot find symbol method showErrorDialog(ConnectionResult)

Error:(137, 13) error: cannot find symbol method showSignedOutUI()

I apologize in advance if this is a newbie question, is it because I've forgotten to import something? I've tried importing many other different components but it did not solve the issue.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes; 
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

I'm a lost sheep here, any help i would greatly appreciate!

Comment: What does your class declaration look like?

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener { `
sorry if it looks messy!
is this what you're looking for? >< @JonK

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare it as `private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to get these methods from google's github over here
-> https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin
and define them myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do not post additional information as answer to your question.

Secondary, **cannot resolve symbol method** is always means that method or field doesn't exist in your class or package.